# Problems to reproduce Weight Video buffering php on Chrome

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, video, streaming

I have problems to reproduce a weight video (400mb or more) In Chrome. In Opera and Mozilla Firefox Works.

During the "streaming", I cant navigatintg the site, always is "Charging".

My script is:
http://codesamplez.com/programming/php-html5-video-streaming-tutorial

I tried to increment the buffering, but not works.

The videos are about the root folder and I have to access with HEADER.

I have problems  with the script to download videos too, I cant navigatintg the site, always is "Charging" :

```
$local_file = $url;
$download_file = $url;

// set the download rate limit (=> 20,5 kb/s)
$download_rate = 140;
if(file_exists($local_file) && is_file($local_file))
{
    header('Cache-control: private');
    header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($local_file));
    header('Content-Disposition: filename='.basename($download_file));

    flush();
    $file = fopen($local_file, "r");
    while(!feof($file))
    {
        // send the current file part to the browser
        print fread($file, round($download_rate * 1024));
        // flush the content to the browser
        flush();
        // sleep one second
        sleep(1);
    }
    fclose($file);}
}
```

Thx you.

Comment: You are only sending `$download_rate * 1024` bytes every second or in other words 14 KB every second... Not sure where you get 20.5 kb/s. The site is always loading because you are always sending data to the browser (especially with larger files).

In the link you posted they are actually sending all the data as fast as they can (not waiting one second every loop).

Comment: I update the download_rate to 1024, but the error is the same.

I tried too push sleep(1); on private function stream, after echo $data, but on chrome cant navigating while the streaming is working.

I dont know what is happening

Comment: That is 1MB a second... It will take 400 seconds to download a 400MB file or 7 minutes roughly. So for 7 minutes the page will be loading.

Comment: That is true, but on Firefox or opera i can continúe navigating while the download or streaming is in progress.  In Chrome the browser is blocked. This is not normal.

Comment: Then it is an issue with how chrome handles receiving data.... Not with your code.

Comment: =( thx you  honerlawd